# Hawt IO - To build HawtIO common dashboard for clustered instances of camel application

Tags: jboss, monitor, ibm-was, hawtio

We are planning to use HAWTIO to monitor the camel instances. Our application is web application which will be running into clustered instances of Websphere application server 7. We want to monitor the clustered instances from different JVM probably from WAS7 JVM or Jboss JVM. 
Currently same JVM hawtIO web is working prefectly. Now I want to try remote instances. HawtIO Connect option is used with host and port of remote instances. I think context name or url is not correct to get data from jolokia agent running in remote jvm. Please advice on this.

Comment: What context did you configure the jolokia agent to listen on in the remote JVM?  The default settings in hawtio's connection tab would expect to connect to http://localhost:8181/jolokia

Comment: I am using maven build and added one of dependency as hawtio-web. This  enrich my webapp with hawtio stuff. I believe jolokia agent will be part of web app itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WAS7 I would suggest to deploy the jolokia agent as a WAR which is also what jolokia recommends: http://jolokia.org/agent/war.html

You should be able to access that url from a web browser. Then make sure this works first.
Then you can use hawtio to access that url also in the remote connection dialog.

Comment: Thanks for information. Let me try it and share the feedback